# How can I access the DOM of a chrome extension from a regular web page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a standard web page that runs inside of a chrome tab. There is a third party chrome extension that I would like to access its DOM elements from my web page. I have no control over this extension and cannot access the extension's source code.

I would like to be able to access html elements and hook into events in this extension from my web page. Is this possible?

Please provide working source code as I am new to chrome extensions.

I tried searching on google and using the chrome extension api page. The examples that I found are around going from the extension to the web page. I need to do the reverse.

It does seems message passing between the two is possible but again that's not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: No, it's not possible by design.

Comment: Thank you and it does make sense, but is there anything else I could possibly do to know what is happening within the html of the chrome extension (even without being able to control their code)?